# Linked List Concatenation In O(1) Time

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I came upon an interesting question and I am puzzled with the answer provided to me. The question is as follows:

```
The concatenation of 2 lists can be performed O(1) time. 
Which of the following implementation of list should be used?

 - Singly Linked List 
 - Doubly Linked List
 - Circular Linked List
 - Array Implementation Of Linked List
```

I initially thought that a DLL would be the correct choice as concatenation can happen from both side, however the answer seems to CLL. 
I am confused.
Any explanation will be most helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do it in O(1) with any implementation that uses pointers and in which you can get to the last element in one operation.  CLL lets you do a back from the head element to get to the end, then you update a few pointers and you're done.  However, if you just have a member that points at the last element, you can use any other pointer based implementation just as well.

Comment: The question as stated doesn't provide enough information to answer it. It all depends on how quickly you can access the tail of a list, and singly, doubly, and circularly linked lists can all be implemented in ways that give quick access to the tail or ways that require the whole list to be traversed to do that.

Comment: Also, an array-based implementation isn't a linked list.

Comment: @user2357112: Where is the "tail" of a circular linked list? And you *can* implement a linked list in an array. The node pointers are just indexes into the array.

Comment: @JimMischel: Whichever node represents the last element. The link structure might not have a beginning or end, but we still generally have a notion of a starting point.

Comment: @JimMischel: As for node pointers being indexes into an array, sure, you can do that, but at that point you're just emulating memory. You can implement any data structure in an array that way. I don't think that's the kind of implementation the question is talking about; it sounds a lot more like a standard dynamic array implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily concatenate two lists in O(1) time using either a single linked list or a doubly linked list, provided that you have a pointer to the last node in at least one of the lists. (And, of course, pointers to the list heads.)

You can't do it with an array implementation, because you end up having to allocate more memory and copy the new resulting list to it. Even if the array already has memory allocated, you still have to copy all of the new items to it. So it's either O(m+n) or O(n) (where m and n are the lengths of the individual lists, respectively).

With a circularly linked list, you can easily concatenate them in O(1) time. It's just a matter of breaking a link in both lists, and then hooking them together. This assumes, of course, that the order of items isn't especially important.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is Circular doubly linked List

For merging of list you have to point next pointer of last node of 1st list to first node of 2nd list. To do this in
O(1) time circular doubly linked list is useful. You can go to last node of 1st list by head1->next->previous. And modify this
field pointing to head2->next. And also modify head2->next->previous to head1->next.

If in sinlgy and doubly linked list pointer to last node of any one list is given then you can do the merging of two list in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be multiple correct answers.

You can concatenate two singly-linked lists in O(1) time as long as you store pointers to both the first and last elements of the list. You'd just rewire the next pointer of the last element of the first list to the first element of the second list. This also works with doubly-linked lists.

You can also concatenate two circularly-linked lists in O(1) time by using a similar trick.

The only option that doesn't work is the array-based list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `last`, but you do need a `next`

Assume the each list has at least two elements

```
void merge( node* first, node* second )
{
  node * first_next = first->next;
  node * second_next = second->next;

  first->next = second_next;
  second->next = first_next;
}
```

As Jim Mischel has said, **any** list will work just fine.

Comment: Thnaks man, I was looking for some kind of code or diagram. You provided exactly what I needed.
After going through several articles, still I had doubts. Your code helped me understand it.

Comment: Did you actually try this? From my understanding this swaps the first element of each list, without doing an actual concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

These two:

- Doubly Linked List
- Circular Linked List

are correct answers. Both support O(1) concatenation.

Comment: Doubly linked list is not correct since it requires O(n) iterations to find the last node.

The correct answer is: 
Circular Linked List