# Find number of leaves under each node of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have a tree which is represented in the following format:

- nodes is a list of nodes in the tree in the order of their height from top. Node at height 0 is the first element of nodes. Nodes at height 1 (read from left to right) are the next elements of nodes and so on.
- n_children is a list of integers such that n_children[i] = num children of nodes[i]

For example given a tree like {1: {2, 3:{4,5,2}}}, nodes=[1,2,3,4,5,2], n_children = [2,0,3,0,0,0].

Given a Tree, is it possible to generate nodes and n_children and the number of leaves corresponding to each node in nodes by traversing the tree only once?

Is such a representation unique? Or is it possible for two different trees to have the same representation?

Comment: `is it possible for two different trees to have the same representation` - doesn't seem so: by definition the representation defines the tree so two identical representations constitute the same tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For the first question - creating the representation given a tree:

I am assuming by "a given tree" we mean a tree that is given in the form of node-objects, each holding its value and a list of references to its children-node-objects.

**I propose this algorithm:**

1. Start at `node=root`.
2. if `node.children` is empty return `{values_list:[[node.value]], children_list:[[0]]}`
3. otherwise:

   3.1. construct two lists. One will be called `values_list` and each element there shall be a list of values. The other will be called `children_list` and each element there shall be a list of integers. Each element in these two lists will represent a level in the sub-tree beginning with `node`, including `node` itself (will be added at step 3.3).

   So `values_list[1]` will become the list of values of the children-nodes of `node`, and `values_list[2]` will become the list of values of the grandchildren-nodes of `node`. `values_list[1][0]` will be the value of the leftmost child-node of `node`. And `values_list[0]` will be a list with one element alone, `values_list[0][0]`, which will be the value of `node`.

   3.2. for each child-node of `node` (for which we have references through node.children):

   3.2.1. start over at (2.) with the child-node set to `node`, and the returned results will be assigned back (when the function returns) to `child_values_list` and `child_children_list` accordingly.

   3.2.2. for each index `i` in the lists (they are of same length) if there is a list already in `values_list[i]` - concatenate `child_values_list[i]` to `values_list[i]` and concatenate `child_children_list[i]` to `children_list[i]`. Otherwise assign `values_list[i]=child_values_list[i]` and `children_list[i]=child.children.list[i]` (that would be a push - adding to the end of the list).

   3.3. Make `node.value` the sole element of a new list and add that list to the beginning of `values_list`. Make `node.children.length` the sole element of a new list and add that list to the beginning of `children_list`.

   3.4. return `values_list` and `children_list`
4. when the above returns with `values_list` and `children_list` for `node=root` (from step (1)), all we need to do is concatenate the elements of the lists (because they are lists, each for one specific level of the tree). After concatenating the list-elements, the resulting `values_list_concatenated` and `children_list_concatenated` will be the wanted representation.

In the algorithm above we visit a node only by starting step (2) with it set as `node` and we do that only once for each child of a node we visit. We start at the root-node and each node has only one parent => every node is visited exactly once.

**For the number of leaves associated with each node:** (if I understand correctly - the number of leaves in the sub-tree a node is its root), we can add another list that will be generated and returned: `leaves_list`.
In the stop-case (no children to `node` - step (2)) we will return `leaves_list:[[1]]`. In step (3.2.2) we will concatenate the list-elements like the other two lists' list-elements. And in step (3.3) we will sum the first list-element `leaves_list[0]` and will make that sum the sole element in a new list that we will add to the beginning of `leaves_list`. (something like `leaves_list.add_to_eginning([leaves_list[0].sum()])`)

---

#### For the second question - is this representation unique:

To prove uniqueness we actually want to show that the function (let's call it `rep` for "representation") preserves distinctiveness over the space of trees. i.e. that it is an [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). As you can see in the wiki linked, for that it suffices to show that there exists a function (let's call it `tre` for "tree") that given a representation gives a tree back, and that for every tree t it holds that `tre(rep(t))=t`. In simple words - that we can make a method that takes a representation and builds a tree out of it, and for every tree if we make its representation and passes that representation through that methos we'll get the exact same tree back.

So let's get cracking!

Actually the first job - creating that method (the function `tre`) is already done by you - by the way you explained what the representation is. But let's make it explicit:

1. if the lists are empty return the empty tree. Otherwise continue
2. make the root node with `values[0]` as its value and `n_children[0]` as its number of children (without making the children nodes yet).
3. initiate a list-index `i=1` and a level index `li=1` and level-elements index `lei=root.children.length` and a next-level-elements accumulator `nle_acc=0`
4. while `lei>0`:
   4.1. for `lei` times:
   4.1.1. make a node with `values[i]` as value and `n_children[i]` as the number of children.
   4.1.2. add the new node as the leftmost child in level `li` that has not been filled yet (traverse the tree to the `li` level from the leftmost in right direction and assign the new node to the first reference that is not assigned yet. We know the previous level is done, so each node in the `li-1` level has a `children.length` property we can check and see if each has filled the number of children they should have)
   4.1.3. add `nle_acc+=n_children[i]`
   4.1.4. increment `++i`
   4.2. assign `lei=nle_acc` (level-elements can take what the accumulator gathered for it)
   4.3. clear `nle_acc=0` (next-level-elements accumulator needs to accumulate from the start for the next round)

Now we need to prove that an arbitrary tree that is passed through the first algorithm and then through the second algorithm (this one here) will get out of all of that the same as it was originally.

As I'm not trying to prove the corectness of the algorithms (although I should), let's assume they do what I intended them to do. i.e. the first one writes the representation as you described it, and the second one makes a tree level-by-level, left-to-right, assigning a value and the number of children from the representation and fills the children references according to those numbers when it comes to the next level.

So each node has the right amount of children according to the representation (that's how the children were filled), and that number was written from the tree (when generating the representation). And the same is true for the values and thus it is the same tree as the original.

The proof actually should be much more elaborate and detailed - but I think I'll leave it at that now. If there will be a demand for elaboration maybe I'll make it an actual proof.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But this algorithm gives me the elements in the depth first order. I need them to be in the breadth first order.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I understand you are referring the first algorithm. It produces the representation you specified, and specifically - you get the nodes by levels - first the root, then all the root's children, then the root's grandchildren and so on. Where do you see depth first order? The algorithm goes into depth first (as it uses recursion) but that's not the order of what it returns. That's the whole point of keeping a list for each level while traversing the tree. Only after the traverse finishes the lists are concatenated and returned.

Comment: So there's two things to consider here actually. First, to flatten out an arbitrary list of nested lists, one needs to traverse the lists again right? Or is there another way to do it? Secondly, given a tree like {1:{2:{6,7},3:{4,5}}} I need the output to be [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5]. Your algorithm gives me [1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5]. That is what I meant by depth first.

Comment: Regarding the complexity - you specified only that you want to traverse the *tree* only once, so I didn't give it much thought before. But yes, you can concatenate 2 lists in O(1) look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938499/linked-list-concatenation-in-o1-time). Once you have a O(1) concatenation in place you only need to go through the list of lists so you get O(k) where k=number_of_lists=tree's_height. You have also concatenations within the recursive algorithm (steps (1) through (3) in first algorithm) but that wouldn't be a seconds traverse - just part of the first one.

Comment: Regarding correctness - I'm not sure how you got to this result. Just to make sure I took your example and ran it manually through the algorithm and got (as expected) values_list_concatenated=[1,2,3,6,7,4,5], children_list_concatenated=[2,2,2,0,0,0,0].
Did you clock the fact that it has another indentation that OS won't show - that step (3.2) is a loop and steps (3.2.1) and (3.2.2) are performed for each child-node of `node` *before* continuing to step (3.3)? Meaning we continue to step (3.3) with `node` only after we finished performing (3.2.1+2) for ALL of `node`'s children?

Comment: If it helps, here is a naive implementation (the concatenation for example is not O(1) here), with the example you provided, and it generates the wanted results (same ones I wrote above): [javascript implementation jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et_l/htrqcpzz/).

Note that this implementation takes trees in the form of `{value:<root_val>, children:<array of children-objects (empty array if no children)>}` 

So your example for it: `{value:1, children:[{value:2, children:[{value:6, children:[]},{value:7, children:[]}]},{value:3, children:[{value:4, children:[]},{value:5, children:[]}]}]}`

Comment: I just understood your answer properly now. It's a brilliant answer. I implemented it a bit differently and was hence getting different results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help :)